# Alfresco Share: Retrieve config data from Java

Tags: share, alfresco

I'd like to access `share-config-custom.xml` data from a Java bean in the Share webapp.

What is the equivalent to the following javascript syntax (which access the config root object) but in a Java context:

```
config.scoped['RepositoryLibrary']['root-node']
```

Is the share-config-custom translated to a bean itself? Or is there an API to read it from Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no "reasonable" way to use this API "looking" at one XML config file. In gen eral, the `ConfigService` creates a configuration merging from various sources. But looking directly at the XML should not be needed anyways.

That being said, the Javascript object `config` actually is a  `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptConfigModel`.

To get something equivalent in Java get yourself a reference to the `ConfigService`. To obtain the reference, let spring inject it in your custom bean:

```
<property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
```

Calling `configService.getGlobalConfig()` should get you the equivalent of `config.scoped`.

Comment: Hi ... I want to update the existing config.. I mean that I need to reload the xml which is already there in config service.. is that possible this way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but Andreas' answer only got me halfway there. The configuration class is actually the XMLConfigService now.

Here's a code snippet that worked with Enterprise 4.1.* Alfresco:

Java class

```
import org.springframework.extensions.config.xml.XMLConfigService;

public class PDFValidate extends BaseJavaDelegate implements ExecutionListener
{
    protected XMLConfigService configService;

    public void setConfigService( XMLConfigService scriptConfigModel )
    {
        this.configService = scriptConfigModel;
    }
```

Bean registration:

```
<bean id="AbstractWorkflowDelegate" parent="baseJavaDelegate" abstract="true" depends-on="activitiBeanRegistry" />

<bean id="PDFValidate" parent="AbstractWorkflowDelegate" class="com.epnet.alfresco.metadata.listener.PDFValidate">
    <property name="repository" ref="repositoryHelper" />
    <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
</bean>
```

And from there, you can use the configService in your java code to get the config values.
The XMLConfigService is located in the spring-surf-core-configservice-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar for my version of Alfresco.

Comment: thanks... So now could you able to access this way ...config.scoped['RepositoryLibrary']['root-node']